# Why 0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3 in D?

Tags: floating-point, floating-accuracy, d, constantfolding

```
assert(0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3); // shall be true
```

is my favorite check that a language uses native floating point arithmetic.

### C++

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
   printf("%d\n", (0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3));
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
```

http://ideone.com/ErBMd

### Python

```
print(0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3)
```

Output:

```
True
```

http://ideone.com/TuKsd

### Other examples

- Java: http://ideone.com/EPO6X
- C#: http://ideone.com/s14tV

Why is this not true for D? As understand D uses native floating point numbers. Is this a bug? Do they use some specific number representation? Something else? Pretty confusing.

### D

```
import std.stdio;

void main()
{
   writeln(0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3);
}
```

Output:

```
false
```

http://ideone.com/mX6zF

---

### UPDATE

Thanks to [LukeH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55847/lukeh). This is an effect of Floating Point Constant Folding described [there](http://www.d-programming-language.org/float.html).

Code:

```
import std.stdio;

void main()
{
   writeln(0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3); // constant folding is done in real precision

   auto a = 0.1;
   auto b = 0.2;
   writeln(a + b != 0.3);     // standard calculation in double precision
}
```

Output:

```
false
true
```

http://ideone.com/z6ZLk

Comment: Please put relevant code examples directly in the question and not at external links. Both to make sure that the full information in the question survives and to make it easier to read.

Comment: I was going to reflexively click the close button until I noticed you wrote `==` instead of `!=`.

Comment: Regarding your update: This is not a "problem" with the compiler optimiser. It's legal floating-point behaviour, and the possibility of this happening is explained in the ["Floating Point Constant Folding" section](http://www.d-programming-language.org/float.html) of the D documentation.

Comment: Please look at what happens when you use the `real` type instead of the `double` type: http://ideone.com/NAXkM

Comment: @Jean Hominal: Case with real type is interesting. Thinking...

Comment: @Anders Abel: Added code examples, but for C++ and Python only. Java and C# are too verbose imho :)

Comment: Computerphile  has an amazing video explaining floating points  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0

Comment: It happens also in Ruby

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It's probably being optimized to (0.3 != 0.3). Which is obviously false. Check optimization settings, make sure they're switched off, and try again.

Comment: Wait, why would the compiler do decimal floating point calculation and the runtime do binary floating point calculation?

Comment: Good point. The funny thing is, I just tried this, and I'm getting false; I can't repro the OP's result myself. I'm compiling to 32 bit though, I'm wondering if 64 bit makes a difference.

Comment: This is the correct answer. See the "Floating Point Constant Folding" section of http://www.d-programming-language.org/float.html.

Comment: Well, I just tried asserting 0.1f + 0.2f != 0.3f and that does evaluate to true.

Comment: Definately something with optimization. Tried the same with variables and got true: http://ideone.com/zO4OD

Comment: From [the link I posted in my comment](http://www.d-programming-language.org/float.html): "Different compiler settings, optimization settings, and inlining settings can affect opportunities for constant folding, therefore the results of floating point calculations may differ depending on those settings."

Comment: Heh, I just re-read the question; I thought by 'D', you meant the fourth example in that list; I was trying to repro it in C#!

Comment: Interestingly IEEE 754 has a new(ish) data type called decimal32 (and decimal64) . Most people think of floating point as "binary32" and "binary64" as defined by spec. The useful types ( what many people "mean" by floating point ) is actually decimal64.

Does D's language allow specification of whether a float is "binary" or "decimal", and does it include that for constants? 

Using "0.2" in a language without any type specifier for the constant seems like part of the problem.

Answer (score 53):

<sub>(Flynn's answer is the correct answer. This one addresses the problem more generally.)</sub>

---

You seem to be assuming, OP, that the floating-point inaccuracy in your code is deterministic and *predictably wrong* (in a way, your approach is the polar opposite of that of people who don't understand floating point yet).

Although (as Ben points out) floating-point inaccuracy *is* deterministic, from the point of view of your code, if you are not being very deliberate about what's happening to your values at every step, this will not be the case. Any number of factors could lead to `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` succeeding, compile-time optimisation being one, tweaked values for those literals being another.

Rely here *neither* on success nor on failure; do not rely on floating-point equality *either way*.

Comment: That's a very good point - you can't rely on floating point arithmetic to give you the wrong answer! :-)

Comment: Floating-point inaccuracy DOES yield deterministic, predictable answers... as long as you use sequence points and assignments to variables to force rounding at every step.  And, beware of compiler options which will eliminate rounding, for example with MSVC `/fp:precise` should be used.

Comment: This is a terrible explanation. IEEE 754 unambiguously define basic operations including `+`. The problem here is one of programming language, not of floating-point. Also, floating-point equality is perfectly defined. You shouldn't use it when it's not what you want, that's all.

Comment: @Pascal: IEEE 754 does. D does not. You assert that "the problem here is one programming language", and... you're right! If you look at the question *really* closely, you'll see that it is tagged `d`, not `IEEE 754`. I really hope that helps you understand the question.

Comment: @Ben: Sure, if you control all of those factors. My answer does presume that the programmer doesn't do that. I edited my answer to word that better.

Answer (score 5):

According to my interpretation of the [D language specification](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/float.html), floating point arithmetic on x86 would use 80 bits of precision internally, instead of only 64 bits.

One would have to check however that that is enough to explain the result you observe.

Comment: Woah, @Tomalak, my head's just exploded ;-)

Comment: @Tomalak: as are 0.2 and 0.3 - but rounding with 80-bit of precision instead of 64 could make the value "equal" instead of distinct. And I have just checked with variables with the real type, and it evaluates to false again: http://ideone.com/sIFgk