# Why we can't use operators with floating point numbers?

Tags: c++

What's wrong to use operators while you are using floating point numbers. Can't we use '==' '<=' etc operators with floating point numbers?

here is the code.

```
# include <iostream>

using namespace std;

main(){
 float x, y, z;
 cout<<"1st integer: ";
 cin>>x;

 do {
    cout<<"2nd integer: ";
    cin>>y;
    if(y<=0 ){
            cout<<"You can't divide by zero"<<endl;
            continue;
        } else {
                break;
                }
        } while (1);

z = x/y;
cout<<"Result: "<<z;


}
```

it generate right result as i want to get. But from some where i heard that's not a good logic to use operators with floating point numbers. why?

Comment: Relevant read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3000...4` and is `> 0.3` (not `== 0.3`).

Comment: @Galic, actually it is not unlike that two floating point #s are exactly equal.  In fact, it's probably more likely that they are equal than if you had infinite precision.  For example: float a = 1.0f, b = 1.0f; will surely make a==b.  additionally, a==(b+delta) is also true if delta is below the precision of float.  what is problematic is that sometimes they're not equal when you expect them to be...

Comment: @TonyD  But what will be happened when i use this program in integer variable instead of floating point? I mean if i input the numerator value by 0.50, the loop doesn't break, it continuously runs and display the results, why? Integer drops the decimal numbers, so why it doesn't implement here?

Comment: If you change `y` to `int`, then typing `0.50` results is `0` being parsed into `y` which triggers the "can't divide by zero" message and `continue`, then it tries to parse the "." into an `integer` which is an input error... that doesn't affect `cin` or `y` and you're stuck in the loop.  You should search for some examples of testing for and handling input errors i.e. `if (cin >> y) ... else { cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max, '\n'); std::cin.clear(); };`.  Lots of SO questions explain this.

Answer (score -1):

What you're doing is fine.  What you do need to be wary of is using the equality operator `==` with floating point, because the results may surprise you (eg [`0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874357/why-0-1-0-2-0-3-in-d)).

But there's no problem with using `>`, `>=`, `<=`, `<`.

Comment: *"But there's no problem with using >, >=, <=, <."* - not so - e.g. on [ideone.com here](https://ideone.com/rgZM4j) `.1 + .2 > .3` while `.3 * .3 < .9`.

Comment: @TonyD the first one is a correct example, but `.3*.3` *is* smaller than `.9`, and here `.3*.3==.09` correctly evaluates to true. A better example might be `.2*.2>.04`

Comment: @KillianDS: oh yikes - yeah - rushing to demonstrate stuff you already know, it's easy to be careless... thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can compare floating point numbers safely against precisely zero. This will prevent a division by zero.

What you can't do is check `x==0.1` and then divide by `x-0.1`. Since 0.1 isn't exactly representable, you have rounding in a generally unknown direction.

Comment: This is a bad example. If `x` doesn't compare equal to `0.1`, then `x-0.1` will not compare equal to `0.0`, and can safely be divided by.

Comment: @TonyK: Your statement is true for IEEE754 which has bit-perfect rounding for the 4 basic arithmetic operations, but C++ does not mandate IEEE754.

Comment: `x-0.1` will be _very_ non-zero -- in the worst case, about `0.05 * epsilon` in absolute value. This is `0.1*2^-24` in IEEE 32-bit format; for this format, even without using denormalised numbers, the smallest representable positive number is `2^-126`. This huge difference will not disappear for any realistic floating-point representation.